# Error in reading Dicom file by useing vmtkimagereader

Tags: windows

I have just started to use vmtk. I installed it on windows using vmkt installer for windows from here. Now I am trying to continue by the tutorial of the vmtk. One of the first steps in the tutorial is reading dicom files which are in a directory and convert them to a .vti file. I used following command line that is described here:

> vmtkimagereader -f dicom -d dicom_directory_path --pipe
>   vmtkimagevoiselector -ofile image_volume_voi.vt

but I have faced with the following error:

> vmtkimagereader error: unknown option -d

what can I do?